# Главное() — запятая или тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Какой знак нужно поставить после слова "главное" в предложении:
**Главное(?) посмотреть на происходящее с другой стороны.**

Answer (score 7):

В этом предложении возможны варианты постановки знаков препинания. Они зависят от интонации и смысла предложения, от роли слова ГЛАВНОЕ в предложении.

Во-первых, ГЛАВНОЕ здесь может выполнять роль субстантивированного подлежащего при сказуемом, выраженном инфинитивом. В этом случае предполагается длинная пауза и ставится тире.

Во-вторых,  слово ГЛАВНОЕ очень часто выступает в роли вводного слова. В этом примере, конечно, его тоже можно расценить как вводное, и тогда нужна запятая. Интонация уже другая, пауза короткая.

**ГЛАВНОЕ**, **вводное слово**
Указывает на то, что говорящий намерен высказать важную, особенно существенную мысль.
*«Вот мы и дома, – промолвил Николай Петрович, снимая картуз и встряхивая волосами. – Главное, надо теперь поужинать и отдохнуть». И. Тургенев, Отцы и дети.* [Здесь](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_136)

Answer (score 4):

Между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженным неопределенной формой глагола, ставится тире.
Главное ***— посмотреть*** на происходящее с другой стороны.

Comment: @Aer  Возможно, я не права, но! - прежде чем "пинать" Ахмеда Ибрагимова - Вам(как модератору) нужно было бы посмотреть на ответ _Сержа_, чтобы понять: что и он, и Вы ошиблись: "Между подлежащим и сказуемОм (?) (выраженнОГО (?) неопределенной формой глагола, ставится тире). Главное - посмотреть на происходящее с другой стороны". А что вы делаете на этом сайте?" Он ведь(А.И.) - отчасти - прав!

Comment: @Aer Просто новый участник, у которого нет пока прав ни на комментарии, ни на правки, пытался указать на ошибки-описки трехлетней давности, которые никто не заметил. КАК быть в этом случае? Это ведь и не  спам и не оскорбление.