# Знаки препинания в предложении "Главное меру знать"

Tags: пунктуация

"Главное меру знать" — нужно ли после первого слова ставить тире или запятую? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: [Повтор вопроса](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/42382/%d0%93%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5)

Comment: Серж, думаю, не совсем повтор. Здесь предложение ближе к устойчивому сочетанию.

Comment: Здесь важно не то, что чем выражено, а структура предложения. Т.е. в вашем предложении "главное'' можно рассматривать как подлежащее, а следовательно, поставить тире между подлежащем "главное'' и сказуемым ''мету знать'' или рассматривать "главное'' как вводное'' и поставить запятую.

Comment: Вот уж вводное сюда никак не подходит.

Comment: Надо знать контекст, чтобы понять, подходит или нет.

Answer (score 4):

[Справка Грамоты.ру](http://www.gramota.ru/forum/spravka/48096/) разрешает на выбор пишущего оба знака.

> [Вопрос № 227784](http://pishu-pravilno.livejournal.com/4183800.html)
>
> *Главное чтобы костюмчик сидел - нужна ли запятая?*
>
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>
> *После "главное" нужна запятая или тире.*

С форума, обсуждения:

> *Главное* - подлежащее, *чтобы костюмчик сидел* - именная часть сказуемого. Глагол-связка в нулевой форме, его-то и обозначает тире.

О слове "главное" как вводном - маленькая статья (можно посмотреть [примеры](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_136)):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *Но, главное, Женька...* Интересно, почему после "но" запятая?!

Comment: См. разъяснения про "а главное" (переложимо и на "но"): http://punktuaciya.academic.ru/23/%D0%B0(,)_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5

Answer (score 0):

Это выражение, действительно, близко к устойчивому, и если вы пишете интуитивно, то никакого знака не поставите вовсе, потому что текст произносится без пауз. Очень важна  инверсия, так как именно она переносит ударение на значимое слово "меру": Главное мЕру знать. В таком виде фраза встречается довольно часто.

Здесь после подлежащего "главное" пауза явно отсутствует, в крайнем случае, можно поставить запятую, посчитав "главное" вводным словом: Главное, меру знать. Но это будет правильное оформление обычного выражения, без учета его "фразеологичности".

А вот правильные варианты с тире: Главное - знать меру. Главное - это знать меру.

Примеры устойчивых выражений без постановки тире:Грош цена твоим словам.  Дело дрянь.

Comment: >> *посчитав "главное" вводным словом* А что, любое-любое слово можно при желании "посчитать вводным"?

Comment: Не совсем любое. Это такое  слово, которое можно обособить и которое выражает тематику вводных слов. В нашем случае  это оформление речи, конкретно - выделение главной мысли. Например:    Главное, надо хорошо запомнить обратную дорогу.